# PC stopped seeing AV receiver as sound output device. Further troubleshooting steps I could try?

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi

#### Before the problem:

- Windows 10 Home PC. OS build 19042.1526.
- AMD Ryzen 7 2700X / nVIDIA GTX 1080ti

Sound output to a Yamaha RX-V375 AV receiver via HDMI cable from GPU on this setup.

This setup was working as expected for many months.

#### The problem:

A couple days ago Windows stopped seeing the receiver as "plugged in." It's still listed in the sound control panel but it's labeled "Not plugged in:"

[image: screenshot]

I made no config changes prior to this stoppage of working.

**Steps tried:**

- Replaced HDMI cable.
- Tried all HDMI outputs on PC and inputs on receiver.
- Switched from GPU to motherboard HDMI output.
- Power-cycled everything.
- Reset AV receiver to factory settings.
- Connected to receiver via S/PDIF output. When using S/PDIF out receiver is detected and sound functions normally. **So receiver appears operable probably.** But I'd rather use HDMI.

Anything else I could try?

Any tools/techniques including command-line that could give better insight?

Comment: Check device manager, reinstall Nvidia driver, reinstall audio drivers

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to Control panel>Device manager>select your computer press rmb select "scan for hardware changes".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but had embarrassingly forgotten that in Windows 10 "Display Settings", I had disabled the AV receiver as an external monitor. I did this because most of the time I only use digital optical output for audio as I find it is more reliable if I'm only doing high definition stereo audio. While doing that, I sometimes disable the AVR "monitor" because there is no monitor connected to it, it's just for audio, and I don't want to waste GPU resources. It may be good to check if the monitor is disabled in "Display Settings" if this is still an issue for you.